# Is there a way to use Tor system-wide?

Tags: networking, configuration, proxy, tor

Almost everything is blocked where I am and I need to use a transparent proxy to access anything. I tried using [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) *(online anonymity software)*  but it doesn't work for all the system applications.

I also tried putting 127.0.0.1:8118 in system's proxy settings and applied it system-wide. But It didn't help at all.

Comment: which version of tor you are using? current versions uses `9050` as socks port and `9051` as http port as i used a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: He's probably using Privoxy.  That's port 8118 by default.

Answer (score 12):

All the above steps will make you crazy. I am going to share with you what I have chosen to and works perfectly.

1. Install **torsocks** by going to Ubuntu Software Center and typing "**tor**" and select additional packages.
2. After installation, go to **System Settings... → Network → Network proxy** and enter these settings: `127.0.0.1` and port `9050` into **SOCKS** section.
3. Apply and restart.
4. In all your browsers and apps choose to "**Use System Proxy Settings**".

Comment: works great on Mint 19

Comment: Seems to work nicely with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: there is no Network Proxy section in Network setting in linuxlite/xfce can any bod help me?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [these instructions on using Tor as a transparent proxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy), as provided by the TOR-project itself.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That would be a bit hard.  The instructions are pretty heavy duty iptables settings.  This approach is discouraged anyway - see that link & my answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

Tor provides proxy via both http and socks. So when you want to use it in proxy settings, you need to ensure that you're using correct proxy (http or socks). And check the port before use it.

So Check your tor settings and set proxy accordingly.

You can also use proxy softwares like [FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Izzy mentions, the Tor project itself gives [directions](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy) on how to do what are known as "transparent proxies," though they [highly discourage](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxyLeaks) the practice due to packet leaks.  The alternative are "isolating proxies" that allow you to lock down your network to insure all packets go through Tor.  For more on how to do it if you really want to, you might want to have a look at [my answer to a related question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1083839/242522).  The TorProject.Org approach is thick with IPTables, but there are others.  I also mention isolating alternatives there.